# change text in "Checkout as Guest" in paypal express checkout using PHP

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I am using paypal express checkout. Is there way to change text in "Checkout as Guest" to "Pay with Debit/Credit Card"[Please see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUNVt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately PayPal did not have an API or setting in the account to allow you to change the text. The appearance on the checkout somehow is limited to make a changes and only logo/banner/company name is allowed to be custom.